# how to insert a vector into multi-dimensional vector?

Tags: c++, vector

Lets say i have vector of vectors

```
vector< vector<int> > bigTable;

vector<int> data;
data.resize(2);
fingertable.resize(5,data);
```

How do i insert a vector in?

```
    vector<int> newData;
    newData.resize(2);
    newData.push_back(123);
    newData.push_back(456);
```

When i do the following, the data in the bigTable vector is still 0.

```
bigTable.push_back(newData);
    cout << bigTable[0][0]; // this will produce an output of 0
```

Comment: It is hard to know precisely what you are asking. Please create a short, complete program and paste it into your question. Please tell us what output you see when you run the program, and what output you expected to see.  http://sscce.org/.

Comment: Sorry i misunderstood the "resize" as such my earlier question was a wierd question to ask.

Comment: Please don't completely change the meaning and content of your question once someone's already answered; either post an extension to the question, or start an entirely separate post if necessary.  (FYI: I've rolled your edit back.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you misunderstand what `resize` does (perhaps you're thinking of `reserve`?).  After your second code snippet, `newData` will contain 4 elements: `0`, `0`, `123`, `456`.

Comment: Oh so if i want to save time by declaring a space each time i use push back. the command to use is reserve?

Comment: If that's the case, how do you reserve a 2D vector?

Comment: `vector< vector<int> > bigTable;`
`bigTable.reserve(5);`